# Dynamic Dropdown via PHP and Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Hey im trying to create a dynamic dropdown list using PHP and AJAX. Its worth mentioning that im using visual composer on my wordpress site. So i have to make it a shortcode for visual composer.

Here is currently what ive got.

```
    function dropdownmenu() { 
include_once "connection.php";
?>
    <div class="make">
    <label>Make</label>
        <select name="makelist" onchange="getId(this.value);">
            <option value="">Select Make</option>

        <?php       
        $query = "select distinct(Make) from websitemasterlist order by Make ASC";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        foreach($results as $info) {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $info[Make]; ?>"><?php echo $info[Make]; ?></option>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="model">
    <label>Model</label>
        <select name="model" id="modellist">
            <option value="">Select Model</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getId(val){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getdata.php",
                data: "make="+val,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#modellist").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
<?php
}
add_shortcode('dropdownform','dropdownmenu');

?>
```

I think the error is somewhere in the ajax. because my ajax is weak.

here is the code for the secondary dynamic dropdown

```
<?php
include_once "connection.php";

if (!empty($_POST["make"])) {
    $make = $_POST["make"];
    echo $make;
    $query = "SELECT distinct(Model) FROM websitemasterlist where Make=$make";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    foreach ($results as info2){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo info2["Model"]; ?>"><?php echo info2["Model"]; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

The first dropdown works. but the second dropdown doesn't show any choices when i make a choice on the first dropdown. Any help would be appreciated thank you. Its also worth mentioning that when i try to echo the make .... i dont see the make. so im pretty sure the ajax portion is messed up.

> **The errors I'm getting from the console**

[image]

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: You probably don't want to echo `$make`

Comment: thanks for the help jay. Im unsure of how to see the ajax request response in the browsers developer tool. I have included the jquery library via "<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>". There are no errors reported. Im running this one comugg.com

Comment: ill remove the echo $make. also ill add in prepared statements after i've read more on how to go about it

Comment: You open the developer tools by clicking F12. Dependent on browser you look for a network tab or something similar. Once open, perform the AJAX call.

Comment: I think your javascript wait for json response, but you would like to use html. Your success function won't be fired

Comment: Since `dataType` is unspecified @Peter jQuery will perform a best guess.

Comment: After a little investigating i did get a  error code. Here it is in picture form

https://gyazo.com/d46f75bf6edb726fd1e570e60480cbef

Comment: ok after looking again. i clicked my first drop down and there is a new error now.
https://gyazo.com/c4cbdb73f8919829280a18709cdcfaa7

Comment: The first error says jQuery is not loaded. The second error is because jQuery is not loaded.

Comment: Im not really following what u guys are talking about when you say dataTYpe is unspecified.

Comment: Also, custom.js is not found.

Comment: make sure the path to your jquery is correct, better load jquery from the cdn

Comment: Don't worry about dataType @CharlesPark

Comment: @CharlesPark remove your current jquery script and replace with this one `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: What about custom.js @MasivuyeCokile?

Comment: @JayBlanchard he would need to make sure, that the path is correct for that file

Comment: *I know that* @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: @JayBlanchard as for jquery he used the old way of including the script `<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>` taken from the comments

Comment: That's not "old"

Comment: i tried the replacing the jquery script and it broke a few things on my website on comugg.com. the slider and y product listings dissappeared. also unfortuantely the 2nd dropdown menu still doesnt work. ill leave it in the broken state for now if u guys want to check it out.

Comment: @JayBlanchard it is recommended that  u use `SRI`

Comment: SRI? @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: @CharlesPark `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://comugg.com/wp-content/themes/porto-childjs/custom.js?ver=1.1"></script>` is wrong because you're getting a 404 for this too. Is this the right path?

Comment: @JayBlanchard  Subresource Integrity, which allows browsers to ensure that resources hosted on third-party servers have not been tampered with

Comment: I use a CDN with a backup in the evert the CDN is unavailable @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: i see that there is a "http://comugg.com/wp-content/themes/porto-childjs/custo‌​m.js" in the folder but not a http://comugg.com/wp-content/themes/porto-childjs/custo‌​m.js?ver=1.1"

Comment: @CharlesPark and you m pretty sure u also loading jquery twice u have `jquery-3.2.1.min.js` on the code above and your website source code have `/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4`

Comment: does that mean i should remove the <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt‌​4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> entirely?

Comment: try to remove it and only load your scripts and styles once in the `functions.php` file is this a custom theme or you downloaded it?

Comment: i removed it and most of my website's functions such as the slider and product listing works again. but however im back at the same problem with the second dropdown not populating.

Comment: i bought the theme porto from themeforst.

Comment: it might also help to mention that i used this guide more or less to write this script for a dynamic dropdown list https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8UMCg2KQcsM

Comment: before the loop `var_dump($results)`

Comment: what? i didnt get that at all...

Comment: wanna see if u are getting any results from the query

Comment: $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 
 var_dump($results)
 
 foreach ($results as info2){

added it in between those 2 lines. unfortunately nothing happened

Comment: then there are no results from your db

Comment: im 100% sure the Database is fine. im looking at phpmyadmin and see the database and theres no issue with that.  Also im unable to use echo to see the make from $_post i think theres an issue with the ajax code.

Comment: any additional help would be great @jay and @ masivuye